# How to chunk array with n values to n parts?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with `n` values and I must chunk it to `n` parts. For example I have array with 85487945 values (string) and I must chunk it to 4 parts. ? In php have function for chunk array with n values. Simple using:

```
$array = array();
for($i = 1; $i <= 8; $i++){
    $array[$i] = rand(234, 4364356);
}

$chunked_array = array_chunk($array, 4, true);

print_r($chunked_array);
```

Here array chunked by 4 values to 2 part. How I can chunk array witn 85487945 values to n parts and use it?

Comment: You mean you have 85 million individual values in one array?

Comment: Yes and values in string. It is array and I must chunk to n parts it for using easy.

Comment: *"Here array chunked by 4 values to 2 part."* -- your input array contains **9** entries, `array_chunk()` produces 3 chunks.

Comment: What is your question? How to divide `85487945` by `4`?

Comment: And what on your it is impossible to divide an array with rounding in the big party? Or is the value in your arrays always divisible by 4? @axiac

Comment: In the function `array_chunk()`, breaking an array does not tell where the odd or even odd numbers are divided evenly. @axiac

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`array_chunk`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) takes the size of each "chunk" as a parameter, rather than the number of chunks to produce. You can easily derive one from the other by dividing the size of the array by the desired number:

```
$size = ceil(count($array) / 4);
$chunked_array = array_chunk($array, $size, true);
```

The only non-obvious part might be the call to [`ceil`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php), which ensures you won't end up with some overflow into an extra chunk.

Answer (score 0):

Its a easy way to divide one large element array in to two equal parts.

```
list($left, $right) = array_chunk($large_array, ceil(count($large_array) / 2));
```

Here $large_array is a one big array.
 and in list($left,$right), we passes two parameter,

Here $large_array dividing in two small array is nothing but $left and $right.

After that you can fetch values from both small array using foreach..